# Spree eCommerce - Cannot override css

Tags: css, spree

I need to override my spree store's header colour. I create a custom.css under the ../mystore/vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend directory. But it does not work. please help

The default css style for spree header is shown as below

```
#spree-header #header {
    background: rgba(34,34,34,0.4);
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Below is my custom.css file

```
#spree-header #header {
    background: white !important;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

I expected my spree header to change the colour to white.

Comment: I don't know Spree, but is your css file loaded after the default's one? The order in which css is loaded is important. If you cannot change this (or if it's already in the correct order and still doesn't work) you could try to make your selector more specific (e.g. div#spree-header header#header). Or (if possible) add a class in the html and your css.

Comment: Are you sure that your custom.css is loaded into your page? you can use borwser's DevTools to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *cannot* override an `rgba()` color with an `rgb()` color.

In this instance, `white` is a reserved word, representing `rgb(255, 255, 255)`.

Instead of:

```
background-color: white;
```

use:

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

---

**N.B.** `background` is a multi-value shorthand property.

If you only intend to declare the background color, use `background-color`.

---

For further info on all the values the `background` shorthand property can take, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

For further info on the `background-color` property, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

Comment: Thanks @RezaRamezanpour - that's helpful. It did always used to be the case (perhaps 4-5 years ago?) that `rgb(n, n, n)` would not override `rgba(n, n, n, n)`. From your example, I wonder if the contemporary browser standard is to allow `rgb(n, n, n)` and `rgba(n, n, n, n)` to override each other, now?

Comment: @Rounin Yes,You can easily override them with no problem. i'm not sure about 4-5 years ago, But i never heard it ;-)